# Mostrar mensagem de acordo com a URL

Tags: php

Como faço pra mostrar uma mensagem de acordo com a URL que o usuário estiver acessando?

Por exemplo:

Mensagem:
Você está na página A , quando a url corresponder http://localhost/blog/home/a.php
Você está na página B , quando a url corresponder http://localhost/blog/home/b.php

Comment: $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
       if($actual_link=='http://localhost/blog/home/a.php'){
           echo 'Você está na página A ';  
       }else{
          echo 'Você está na página B ';   
       }

Comment: Um método simples seria você inserir um parametro como váriavel no final da url `http://site.com?a.php?ADM` e recuperar este dado com `$_GET[]` isto usando php ou também utilizando `REQUEST_URI`, também possui formas usando `javascript`, precisa ser em php puro ou pode ser utilizando javascript?

Comment: utilizando o REQUEST_URI seria interessante pra mim poderia ser em php puro mesmo

Comment: Pergunta: são arquivos distintos ou está reescrevendo a URL com *.htaccess*?

Comment: são arquivos distintos

Comment: Então por quê você precisa identificar a URL se saberá qual é o arquivo que estará sendo executado? Basta por no arquivo `a.php` que está na página A e no arquivo `b.php` que está na página B. Ou esta mensagem está em algum código que é incluído em ambos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Usando $_GET

Para usar desta forma você precisa inserir uma variável no link, ou botão que irá redirecionar para a página exemplo `<a href="http://localhost/blog/home/a.php?Pag=a"` e recuperar usado `$_GET[]`

```
$link = $_GET['Pag'];
if($link == a)
{
   echo 'link a';
}else if($link == b)
{
   echo 'link b';
}else{
   echo 'error 404';
}
```

> Usando **FILE**

Pode utilizar o `basename` para retornar o nome do arquivo.php atual

```
$path_parts = pathinfo( __FILE__ );
if($path_parts['basename'] == a.php)
{
    echo 'pagina a';
}else if($path_parts['basename'] == b.php)
{
    echo 'pagina b';
}else{
    echo '404';
}
```

Na sua questão `__FILE__` atende seu problema, mas existem diversas outras formas para usar `basename` para entender melhor como funciona de uma olhada na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.basename.php)